# How to determine if the field is an empty list in MongoEngine?

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I have a field like this in a MongoDB table: "answers":[]

How can I do conditional branch if I want to know it is an empty list?

I'm using Python 2.7 and MongoEngine 0.15.0.

This is what I am trying to do: 
`if object_name.answer is None:`

Is that correct? Please point out if I am on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoengine uses `BaseList` for list field so in this case  `if object_name.answer is None` won't be `True`.

There are two ways you can check if it is empty or not:

```
# first
if object_name.answer == []:
    print('Its empty')

# second
if len(object_name.answer) == 0:
    print('Its empty')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  How is it if the field is in format of EmbeddedDocumentListField? still BaseList?

Comment: Could u help me to vote this question please. Really appreciate!